# The proper ways to stack optioned promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

What would be the proper or the best way to collect all data from DB with promises, but with using native `Node` promises.

The goal is only to present what is selected:

```
const allPromises = [];
const selected = {
  sectionA: true,
  sectionB: false,
  sectionCIds: [ 1, 2, 4 ],
};

if (selected.sectionA) {
  allPromises.push(getSectionADataFromDbPromise());
}
if (selected.sectionB) {
  allPromises.push(getSectionBDataFromDbPromise());
}
if (selected.sectionCIds.length > 0) {
  allPromises.push(selected.sectionCIds
    .map(getSectionCDataFromDbPromise)
  );
}
Promise.all(allPromises)
  .then((allResults) => {
    if (selected.sectionA) {
      dataA = allResults[0];
    }
    if (selected.sectionA) {
      dataB = allResults[1];
    }
    if (selected.sectionC) {
      dataC = allResults[2]; // <-- this will not work if B is not selected
    }

    // ... same logic to build report: return Promise.all()...
  });
```

Possible solutions:

- Track index for each data selected (eg. index of C will be 1)
- Object Map
- Add else `{ allPromises.push(Promise.resolve(null)) }` to every if

Is there maybe an easier or one of this will be the proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `push` on the arrays conditionally, but always put the same value at the same index. Even if the value is nothing - `Promise.all` will handle that just fine.

```
const selected = {
  sectionA: true,
  sectionB: false,
  sectionCIds: [ 1, 2, 4 ],
};
Promise.all([
  selected.sectionA ? getSectionADataFromDbPromise() : null,
  selected.sectionB ? getSectionBDataFromDbPromise() : null,
  Promise.all(selected.sectionCIds.map(getSectionCDataFromDbPromise))
]).then(([dataA, dataB, dataC]) => {
  if (selected.sectionA) {
    // use dataA
  }
  if (selected.sectionA) {
    // use dataB
  }
  if (dataC.length) { // same as selected.selectionCIds.length
    // use dataC
  }
});
```

Comment: Your solution, as I already wrote in the comment will keep the indexes as you return null if a section is not selected. So, the advice against `push` is irrelevant.

Comment: @VladimirVukanac Yes, keeping the indices *is* the proper solution (regardless how exactly you do that). My emphasis was on that you should not push to the array *conditionally*, but rather should always push a value (e.g. by using `push` both in `if` and `else`). Though of course then you can avoid `push` completely and just put everything right in the array literal, which is more concise (and imo more readable).

Comment: So nice and simple

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about this ? It's bigger, it's heavier, it's more difficult, but it's all **automatized** and fully **evolutive**. Wanna handle a new parameter ? A parameter have data now ? Change the map only.

---

I create a map that would contains everything we need to use a loop. The state of the data (activated or not), the function to call to get the data and so on.

```
const mapSelected = {
  sectionA: {
    state: true,

    func: getSectionADataFromDbPromise,
  },

  sectionB: {
    state: false,

    func: getSectionBDataFromDbPromise,
  },

  sectionC: {
    state: true,

    func: getSectionCDataFromDbPromise,

    data: [
      1,
      2,
      4,
    ],
  },
};
```

---

Then we create the promise array using the map we has created. Handling the case with data and without data.

```
const promises = Object.values(mapSelected).reduce((tmp, {
  state,
  func,
  data,
}) => {
  if (!state) return tmp;

  if (data && data.length) {
    return [
      ...tmp,

      ...data.map(x => func.call(this, x)),
    ];
  }

  return [
    ...tmp,

    func.call(this),
  ];
});
```

---

Then we create arrays from the promise return for each key on the map. You can change how I present the data, I didn't knew what you really wanted there.

```
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((allResults) => {
    let i = 0;

    const [
      dataA,
      dataB,
      dataC,
    ] = Object.values(mapSelected).reduce((tmp, {
      state,
      data,
    }, xi) => {
      if (!state) return tmp;

      if (data && data.length) {
        data.forEach(x => (tmp[xi].push(allPromises[i++])));

        return tmp;
      }

      tmp[xi].push(allPromises[i++]);

      return tmp;
    }, Object.values(mapSelected).map(() => []));
  });
```

---

---

**@EDIT**

I just did a snippet about the code I've made, run it

```js
function a() {
  return 1;
}

const mapSelected = {
  sectionA: {
    state: true,

    func: a,
  },

  sectionB: {
    state: false,

    func: a,
  },

  sectionC: {
    state: true,

    func: a,

    data: [
      1,
      2,
      4,
    ],
  },
};

const allPromises = [
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
];

let i = 0;

const [
  dataA,
  dataB,
  dataC,
] = Object.values(mapSelected).reduce((tmp, {
  state,
  data,
}, xi) => {
  if (!state) return tmp;

  if (data && data.length) {
    data.forEach(x => (tmp[xi].push(allPromises[i++])));

    return tmp;
  }

  tmp[xi].push(allPromises[i++]);

  return tmp;
}, Object.values(mapSelected).map(() => []));

console.log(dataA);
console.log(dataB);
console.log(dataC);
```

Comment: That *is* heavy and complicated indeed.

Comment: The third part is really hard to read, it throws "tmp not iterable".

Comment: @VladimirVukanac I'm looking at it ATM

Comment: I like the state and the loop part! React like! I will have to refactor the inner of each if in functions. Anyway, that is not an issue here. I am also trying to resolve the third section and to decouple it to be usable from multiple locations.

Comment: @VladimirVukanac I've just recreated the first part with fake Promise data, and it run without problem. Please be sure you have the same thing. Feel free to edit your post using the code you have right know for us to look into it and help you with.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, unlike libraries such as *Q*, the standard `Promise` does not expose a variant of `all` taking an object of promises.

However, we can use the new ES2015 and ES2017 `Object` utility methods to assist us in keeping the code readable.

```
const allPromises = {};
const selected = {
  sectionA: true,
  sectionB: false,
  sectionCIds: [1, 2, 4],
};

if (selected.sectionA) {
  allPromises.sectionA = getSectionADataFromDbPromise();
}
if (selected.sectionB) {
  allPromises.sectionB = getSectionBDataFromDbPromise();
}
if (selected.sectionBIds.length > 0) {
  allPromises.sectionC = Promise.all(selected.sectionBIds
    .map(getSectionCDataFromDbPromise)
  );
}
```

Now we can write

```
Promise.all(Object.entries(allPromises).map(([key, promise]) =>
    promise.then(value => ({[key]: value}))
  ))
  .then(allResults => {
    const results = Object.assign({}, ...allResults);

    const data = {
      a: results.sectionA,
      b: results.sectionB,
      c: results.sectionB && results.sectionC
    };

    // ... same logic to build report: return Promise.all()...
  });
```

Comment: I don't think that `filter` is going to work, as it cannot access the `key` like that. But the filter shouldn't be necessary at all, just do `Object.assign({}, ...allResults)`!

Comment: Why `c: results.sectionB && results.sectionC` ? Section B does not have direct connection with C.